Recommendations on numerical methods and numerical analysis books for machine learning?
I'm self studying maths for machine learning and I have read Introduction to Linear Algebra and Calculus, both by Gilbert Strang. Now I'm going to study optimization, but I also would like to study numerical analysis and methods. If you could recommend me some books I would really appreciate it.
Edit:
Since there are similar questions as the ones Moo gave could you recommend other topics to learn at the same time or before the ones stated?

Yes, thanks. Do I delete the question? Or can you flag it as repeated?

I'm flagging this as a duplicate question.

Justin Solomon “Numerical Algorithms - Methods for Computer Vision, Machine Learning, and Graphics” (2015)
